# Why I receive "Undefined property" errors when calling an object method

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I have written the PHP array class below

```
<?php 
class arrayClass{
    public $myArray = array("dotun", "she-baby", "she-kanyin", "gerrard");
    public function printArray(){
        return $this->myArray;
    }
}
$newArray = new arrayClass();
print_r($newArray->printArray);
?>
```

But I get `Notice: Undefined property: arrayClass::$printArray in C:\wamp\www\oop\newoop.php on line 9`

Where is my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printArray()` is a function use `()`:

```
print_r($newArray->printArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print_r($newArray->printArray());
```

`printArray` a function and u are trying to get as variable and hence it was showing error.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use () at the end after you type your function.

```
print_r($newArray->printArray());
```